# how to pass language in speech recognition on android apps?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I've been working on speech Recognition API in android and found out that the speech results vary allot when the language settings are changed , is there a way to set it programmatically ? or is there an intent to lunch the speech language settings screen ? or what else ? note: I tried to use this intent extra:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-US");
```

and

```
Intent detailsIntent =  new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, new LanguageDetailsChecker(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by results vary a lot?

Comment: actually i want to send pragmatically language locale to set the default language to other than english

Comment: can you help me in that plz Egor

Answer (score 2):

Yes hanifs, that method didn't work for me also.

My default device language is English US, but I needed Italian for SR.
Only applying all these three extras I succeded forcing Google Engine (used as default speech engine from my device) to use Italian.

```
String myLanguage = "it"; //or, Locale.Italian.toString()
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, myLanguage);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage); 
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage);
```

Try this way customizing your "myLanguage" variable, it should be ok!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do for now is

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, Locale.getDefault());
```

It may not work if the recognizer engine does not support this language.