# Language recognition only works if I change the system language input

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have an english/french application. Defining the EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE is not enough. My app works well as long as I change the system language input to map the target desired language.

Any idea if I do something wrong? Below is the code I'm using.

```
private void initSpeech(){
    Context context;
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
    mListener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            String s = null;
            int ifl = 0;

            ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            spoken.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            assert thingsYouSaid != null;
            for(int i = 0; i<thingsYouSaid.size(); i++) {
                if(thingsYouSaid.get(i).equals(words[curr_pos])) {
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dict_spoken_word)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(i));
                    ifl = 1;
                    s = thingsYouSaid.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(ifl == 0) {
                s = thingsYouSaid.get(0);
                ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dict_spoken_word)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));
            }

            excellent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (lang == 0) {
                if (s.equals(words[curr_pos])) {
                    excellent.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp);
                    count = 0;
                    return;
                }
                count++;
                excellent.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                if (count == 1) {
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp1);
                } else if (count == 2)
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp2);
                else {
                    excellent.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp3);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (s.equals(words[curr_pos])) {
                    excellent.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp_fr);
                    count = 0;
                    return;
                }
                count++;
                excellent.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                if (count == 1) {
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp1_fr);
                } else if (count == 2)
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp2_fr);
                else {
                    excellent.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    excellent.setText(R.string.dict_resp3_fr);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            if(speech_started) speech.stopListening();
            speech_started = false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }
    };
    speech.setRecognitionListener(mListener);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    if(lang == 0)
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-US");
    else
      recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "fr");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            getActivity().getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
}

private void speakDict(){
    ttobj.speak(words[curr_pos], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

private void talk2Me(){
     new CountDownTimer(600, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //        if(speech_started) speech.stopListening();
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        }
    }.start();
}

private void waitForResult(){
    new CountDownTimer(600, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
         }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: set the current locale programmatically.

Comment: You included a lot of irrelevant code in your post.  It's helpful to include a simple example that has just enough code for others to reproduce your problem--see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the language without changing the locale, I used the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21792390).  I was able to get a test app to transcribe in french while my locale was US:

```
private void initSpeech(){
    ...
    String myLanguage;
    if (!isFrench) {
      myLanguage = "en-US";
    } else {
      myLanguage = "fr";
    }
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, myLanguage);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage);
    ...
}
```

You'd need to make sure to call `initSpeech()` any time the language changed, or the intent will still have the old language flags.